# how to open new activity inside another activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

i am new to android and i m developing a photoshop application. in my application i had main activity (screen) with 2 buttons loadimage and exit, if i press on loadimage my program should read image from the gallery and if press on exit, application will exit. my problem is after reading image from the gallery i want to open another activity where i can able to edit that image. i want to know where to start the new activity? because i m getting image in onActivityResult of my main activity, which is the result of second activity.if anyone knows the answer help. thanks in advance.

Comment: The exit button is not a good idea in Android. The user can leave your app with the BACK button or the HOME button. Exit button is not recommended in your UI.

Comment: You may start a new activity from `onActivityResult` in a usual way. Please refer to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#StartingAnActivity).

Answer (score 0):

There, in you onActivityResult you can launch the new Activity to edit the selected image. You just need:

```
Intent goToEditActivity = new Intent (this, EditActivity.class);
goToEditActivity.putExtra ("picturePath", picturePath);
startActivity (goToEditActivity);
```

where picturePath is passed as an extra, so the new activity can show it. Instead of EditActivity.class you should write your activity name. Don't forget to add it to the manifest.